# How to run Junit5 tests in a kubernetes pod without gradle or maven just minimal support

Tags: java, kubernetes, junit

Overview:  I have a frontend service running in a Kubernetes pod that I want to run integration tests on to assure that the backend services do what is expected.  The service uses junit tests that I have repurposed to be integration tests.  And that runs fine in a development environment, but we need them to run in a set of (canary) test pods that mimic our eventual SaaS solution so that we can make them part of our CI/CD pipeline that needs to run on each merge request.  That way people won't be able to check in code that "breaks the build".

So, what I need to find is how to have the minimal stuff to add to our front end (canary) test pod to allow it to run these junit tests.

I found junit5 via apt-get and in it is junit-platform-console-standalone-1.3.2.jar.  That is the start of what I need, but the tests reference org.junit.jupiter.api.Test (and Disabled) and other files in our test classes (e.g. FooTestBaseClass.java) and our tests in the development world are in /foo/src/test/java/com/bar/foo/test with resources in /foo/src/test/resources.

***So, I need to know where to "put" the org.junit.jupiter.api directory as well as what to put in my classpath to find the local java classes.***

The stuff works by "magic" incantations in the development environment, e.g. I just type "gradle test", but I don't want to replicate that entire environment in the Kubernetes pod.  I want to understand the "sufficiently advanced technology" so that it is no longer magic.

Note, I can't run the integration tests in the CICD pipeline outside the pod because the backend code is not in Java (it's mostly in Rust) and there is a hardware layer which is currently simulated in C++ and all the communication is done via GraphQL in yaml files.  And the point of these tests are to make certain that the different implementations of the yaml (and the contents in the GraphQL) are speaking compatible dialects.  Thus, I have to spin up 3 different servers.

Partial success.  I found the 1.9.0 version (as a jar file) in the Maven Central repository.  (It took a bit of looking to find that and how to get it as a jar file rather than just a Maven link in xml.)  That satisfies the junit.jupiter packages.

Comment: Maybe this https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/09/01/integration-testing-on-kubernetes-with-junit5/ can help.

Comment: Thanks I read that page (and a few others).  The page that was most helpful was this one: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-run-from-command-line

It shows how to use junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.2.jar (which is part of junit itself) to run without a build system (i.e. no gradle, no maven, no ant), which is what I want.  Most of the other tutorials show you how to use some "tool" that I would have to load into the pod to achieve that purpose.